# C# pass property as params

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I want to create helper for generate  by model with:

- code salt
- control at complie time property name
- generate html from property attributes (DisplayName)

*Helper*

```
    Html.TableHeaderFor(
        Model, 
        m => m.Name, 
        m => m.Id, 
        m => m.Code,
        m => m.Property1.Name
   );
```

*Model*

```
public class Model
{
    public Model Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Item code")]
    public int Code { get; set; }
}
```

**Answer**

```cs
public static void TableHeaderFor<TModel>(
   this HtmlHelper helper, 
   TModel model, 
   params Expression<Func<TModel, object>>[] columns)
{
    foreach (var column in columns)
    {
        var lambda = column as LambdaExpression;
        /*
        Table gereration 
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: Parse in what? I mean, you pass the list of properties to access the strings to be parsed, but what do you do with the parsed values?

Comment: What is your question exactly? Are you asking for how to implement `ParseObject` that can accept either two strings or four strings? That's called overloading.

Comment: I need parse property property list. I need have autocomplete. Should be tested by the compiler. Answer is public void ParseObject<T>(T model, params Func<T,object>[] funcs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void ParseObject(Model m, params Expression<Func<Model, object>>[] args)
{
  ...
}
```

From each expression you can inspect the body and figure the prop info.

Call it like this:

```
ParseObject(m, o => o.Property1, o => o.Property2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't just pass a property and find it, it's not possible (when you're passing Model.MyString, you're just passing a string, the called method has no way to know that it's part of Model nor that it's named MyString, it is not possible, period, don't look further)

What you CAN do if you're willing to change your calling syntax is (depending on what you need) pass in a params of lamda function or expressions (depending on wether you just want IntelliSense & to pass the data or wether you also need to figure out the property name in the called method)

```
public void ParseObject<T>(T model, params Func<T,string>[] funcs)
{
   foreach(var f in funcs)
   {
      var string = f(model); // do whatever you want with string here
   }
}
```

Or the expression method (expressions represent code at runtime, this is, to simplify "half compiled code" so that you can still look into it) :

```
public void ParseObject<T>(T model, params Expression<Func<<T,string>>[] exprs)
{
   foreach(var e in exprs)
   {
      var string = (e.Compile())(model); // do whatever you want with string here
      var targetMember = ((System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression) e.Body).Member; // warning, this will only work if you're properly calling the ParseObject method with the exact syntax i note bellow, this doesn't check that you're doing nothing else in the expressions, writing a full parser is way beyond the scope of this question
     // targetMember.Name will contain the name of the property or field you're accessing
     // targetMember.ReflectedType will contain it's type
   }
}
```

Edit : sample way to call the method with your example, note that this method doesn't work only on Model but on any class!

```
ParseObject(m, m=>m.Property1, m=>m.Property2); // will work with any number of properties you pass in and full IntelliSense.
```